# How do I cheat the Pachinko Machine in Super Mario Sunshine?

Tags: super-mario-sunshine

I just finished Super Mario Sunshine for the first time, and I'm still trying to recover relationships that I lost to the Pachinko Machine level. It's annoying and impossible, but somehow I still want more of it.

I've seen seedrunners cheat it (using glitches, which is Speedrun-Legal), but I've never been able to recreate it myself. Does anyone know how it's done?

Here is a video of what I mean:

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty straight forward and I don't see any major glitches being used here.

There are other videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_eIxdktBC8) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9x7SweHnxE) that complete the pachinko machine in under 30 seconds.

You start by going up the bounce (3 coins)

Land top middle (4th coin)

Jump to mid-top right (5th coin)

Fall directly below the 5th coin to bottom right (6th coin)

Water jet directly left (7th coin)

Go in the back to the start and drop top left (8th coin)

The video that you have linked does not glitch the game, the player simply water jets from the back of the board because it's connected.

Comment: Yeah, looks that way, but when I try it, Mario starts sliding, and I can't use F.L.U.D.D.

Comment: I can second what OP says. I replayed SMS last month and struggled on this level too. The initial bounce off the trampoline, and subsequent ricochet off the curve at the top, causes Mario to have weird momentum that makes it difficult to hit a specific target, especially on the left side.